# New front forks

Tags: mountain-bike, fork, suspension

Looking to replace my front forks for my Scott Scale 30 (2006) - the forks are tapered - any idea how the layperson can work out how to find what forks would be compatible with the bike?

Answer (score 1):

To find compatible fork, you will need to know:

- Wheel size your bike runs.
- Wheel to fork interface type (quick release or through axle).
- Steerer dimensions (length, taper, diameter).
- Brake caliper mount type (IS or post mount for MTB disc brakes, add flat mount for road/CX/gravel bikes).
- Current fork travel or fork travel range that frame supports.
- Axle to crown distance.
- Fork offset.

In your case, you can run pretty much any XC 26" quick release fork in 80-100mm travel range. That includes non-tapered steerer options as well, just get a crown race adapter. Through axle might be an option too if your front wheel hubs supports QR to TA conversion (or you are willing to replace/rebuild the wheel).

Comment: Thanks - I will have a look at the initial bike specs and see if I can find all of this information out.